# If attributes in an interface is unsupported, why does it compile?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, attributes

I want to add attributes to a property as part of an interface's contract. I read this isn't possible because it does add behavior to a class, something that interface aren't used/made for. But if so, why it does compile instead of give an error if it doesn't have effect at all or am I missing something?

```
public class MyAttr : Attribute { }

public interface MyInterface
{
    [MyAttr]
    string Foo { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : MyInterface
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where did you read that?  A reference would be helpful.

Comment: Attributes on/in interfaces are quite common.

Comment: From false assumption you can derive anything...

Comment: I think this should be closed as off-topic as this isn't programming related.

Answer (score 6):

You can add attributes to interface members according to the specification:

**17.2 Attribute specification**

> Attributes can be specified at global scope (to specify attributes on
>   the containing assembly or module) and for type-declarations (§9.6),
>   class-member-declarations (§10.1.5), interface-member-declarations
>   (§13.2), ...

Comment: +1 as soon as I have votes again :) Yet it would be interesting why this is included in the specification, if it then is just ignored and has no effect if added in code (which, in my eyes, could lead to bugs which are hard to detect)

Comment: What do you mean? You can reflect over attributes in an interface just as well as you can in any other type. They just aren't passed along to implementing classes (which isn't the case with subclasses either).

Comment: @MarkusWeninger attributes "ignored" everywhere - they have no impact on anything but metadata (except couple very special cases like StructLayoutAttribute)... Please clarify your comment as it may shed some light on OP's misconception too.

Comment: Okay, I have been mislead by the paramter `bool inherit` in [MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kff8s254(v=vs.110).aspx). I have assumed that when this parameter is set to true, it will look upwards the inheritance chain, yet in "Remarks" it states `This method ignores the inherit parameter for properties and events.`. So I have to admit I made wrong assumptions. EDIT: Here is a dotnetfiddle, in which I assumed that both, `MyAttr` and `MyAttr2` would show up due to misinterpreting the method: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qqQWAG